# Is there an easy way to fix the black background in latest Firefox update?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, themes

I am using Firefox 95.0.2 on my Win 10 PC without any issues;  I also use a Win 7 PC with latest Firefox 96.0.2 and am not happy with the forced black theme issue.  It is a given that eye safety is a concern but my personal situation with corrective tinted lenses poses a question.  Is there an easy way to opt out or change the black theme configuration of this browser?

Answer (score -1):

#### Is there an easy way to opt out or change the black theme configuration?

1. Open Firefox Setting
2. Go to Extensions and Themes
3. Select a theme with a light colour scheme

[image]